# Data base oracle 10g forms builder gives error in pl\sql commands

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

```
declare

        v1 number(5);


        v3 number(5);


        v2 varchar2(30);

        begin

        select worker.worker_ssn,person.ssn,person.name

      into v1,v3,v2

        from person

        inner join worker

        on person.ssn=worker.worker_ssn



        dbms_output,put_line('ssn is ' || v1 ||' ssn worker is ' || v3 ||' worker 

    name is '|| v2);

        exception

            when to_Many_Rows then

     dbms_output,put_line('more than on row');


        end
```

It gives this error:

> encountered the symbol "join" when expecting one of the following:

Comment: Without mentioning the formatting, your code is full of minor typos: `dbms_output,put_line`, `to_Many_Rows`, missing semi colon at the end of the query, etc.  Please take the time to fix those before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:- Code may give run time error if the select statement returns more that 1 rows.

```
DECLARE
   v1   NUMBER (5);
   v3   NUMBER (5);
   v2   VARCHAR2 (30);
BEGIN
   SELECT worker.worker_ssn, person.ssn, person.name
     INTO v1, v3, v2
     FROM person 
  INNER JOIN worker 
  ON person.ssn = worker.worker_ssn;            

  dbms_output.put_line('ssn is ' || v1 ||' ssn worker is ' || v3 ||' worker  name is '|| v2);


  EXCEPTION

    WHEN too_Many_Rows then

    dbms_output.put_line('more than on row');

 end;
```

Comment: Can you share the ddl scipt for worker and person for me to debug